# Simplify SQL request

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sql query i use in sqlite which in fact is a UNION of 3 SELECT statements.

I'd like to simplify it. Could someone help me?

```
Select *, "A" as Status
  FROM (SELECT ADM_ID,
               Dte_Implantation,
               Dte_modif,
               SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.EMR_ID         as 'EMR_ID',
               SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.STA_NM_ANFR    as 'STA_NM_ANFR',
               SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.EMR_LB_SYSTEME as 'EMR_LB_SYSTEME'
          FROM SUP_STATION_052016
          left outer join SUP_EMETTEUR_052016
            ON SUP_STATION_052016.STA_NM_ANFR =
               SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.STA_NM_ANFR
         WHERE Dte_Implantation >
               (SELECT MAX(Dte_Implantation) FROM SUP_STATION_042016)
           AND (ADM_ID = 6 or ADM_ID = 23 or ADM_ID = 137 or
               ADM_ID = 240))
UNION ALL
select *, "A" as Status
  FROM (SELECT ADM_ID,
               Dte_Implantation,
               Dte_modif,
               SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.EMR_ID         as 'EMR_ID',
               SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.STA_NM_ANFR    as 'STA_NM_ANFR',
               SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.EMR_LB_SYSTEME as 'EMR_LB_SYSTEME'
          FROM SUP_STATION_052016
          left outer join SUP_EMETTEUR_052016
            ON SUP_STATION_052016.STA_NM_ANFR =
               SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.STA_NM_ANFR
         WHERE Dte_modif >
               (SELECT MAX(Dte_Implantation) FROM SUP_STATION_042016)
           AND (ADM_ID = 6 or ADM_ID = 23 or ADM_ID = 137 or
               ADM_ID = 240) EXCEPT
          SELECT ADM_ID,
                 Dte_Implantation,
                 Dte_modif,
                 SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.EMR_ID         as 'EMR_ID',
                 SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.STA_NM_ANFR    as 'STA_NM_ANFR',
                 SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.EMR_LB_SYSTEME as 'EMR_LB_SYSTEME'
                  FROM SUP_STATION_052016
                  left outer join SUP_EMETTEUR_042016
                    ON SUP_STATION_052016.STA_NM_ANFR =
                       SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.STA_NM_ANFR
                 WHERE Dte_modif >
                       (SELECT MAX(Dte_Implantation)
                          FROM SUP_STATION_042016)
                   AND (ADM_ID = 6 or ADM_ID = 23 or ADM_ID = 137 or
                       ADM_ID = 240)
        )
UNION ALL
select *, "S" as Status
  FROM (SELECT ADM_ID,
               Dte_Implantation,
               Dte_modif,
               SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.EMR_ID         as 'EMR_ID',
               SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.STA_NM_ANFR    as 'STA_NM_ANFR',
               SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.EMR_LB_SYSTEME as 'EMR_LB_SYSTEME'
          FROM SUP_STATION_052016
          left outer join SUP_EMETTEUR_042016
            ON SUP_STATION_052016.STA_NM_ANFR =
               SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.STA_NM_ANFR
         WHERE Dte_modif >
               (SELECT MAX(Dte_Implantation) FROM SUP_STATION_042016)
           AND (ADM_ID = 6 or ADM_ID = 23 or ADM_ID = 137 or
               ADM_ID = 240) EXCEPT
          SELECT ADM_ID,
                 Dte_Implantation,
                 Dte_modif,
                 SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.EMR_ID         as 'EMR_ID',
                 SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.STA_NM_ANFR    as 'STA_NM_ANFR',
                 SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.EMR_LB_SYSTEME as 'EMR_LB_SYSTEME'
                  FROM SUP_STATION_052016
                  left outer join SUP_EMETTEUR_052016
                    ON SUP_STATION_052016.STA_NM_ANFR =
                       SUP_EMETTEUR_052016.STA_NM_ANFR
                 WHERE Dte_modif >
                       (SELECT MAX(Dte_Implantation)
                          FROM SUP_STATION_042016)
                   AND (ADM_ID = 6 or ADM_ID = 23 or ADM_ID = 137 or
                       ADM_ID = 240)
        )
```

Comment: You should include some sample with a description as a preface to the problem.  I see nothing inherently evil with doing a `UNION`, though it might be possible to rewrite using joins.

Comment: No problem, it works but far too slow (i have 13 times this request to be executed). just want too simplify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to help with simplifying without actual rewriting a query but i'll try to give general directions that may help.

1) You may unite first and second subquery using something like

```
WHERE (ADM_ID = 6 or ADM_ID = 23 or ADM_ID = 137 or ADM_ID = 240)
  AND (Dte_Implantation > (select max ...)
   OR (Dte_modif > (select max ...)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SUP_STATION_052016 ...)))
```

Of course using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE somefield IS NULL` depends on your DBMS's optimizer, that choice is up to you

2) In addition to that you may also unite the third query by combining `LEFT OUTER JOIN SUP_EMETTEUR_042016 ...` with

```
CASE
  WHEN OneTable.MandatoryField IS NULL AND AnotherTable.MandatoryField IS NOT NULL THEN 'S'
  WHEN OneTable.MandatoryField IS NOT NULL AND AnotherTable.MandatoryField IS NULL THEN 'A'
  WHEN ...
END AS Status
```

3) Also you may try to make a query a bit more readable by using table aliases (just to replace long terms like `SUP_EMETTEUR_042016.EMR_LB_SYSTEME` by something like `SE4.EMR_LB_SYSTEME`). May be replacing long condition `ADM_ID = 6 or ADM_ID = 23 or ADM_ID = 137 or ADM_ID = 240` by a bit shorter `ADM_ID IN (6, 23, 137, 240)` will give a shot too.

4) To improve readability you may try to use common table expressions to get rid of multi-using `(SELECT MAX(Dte_Implantation) FROM SUP_STATION_042016)`

```
WITH max_di AS (SELECT MAX(Dte_Implantation) AS val FROM SUP_STATION_042016)
...(your select here)
FROM max_di
    INNER JOIN SUP_STATION_052016 SS5
            ON (..conditions here..
           AND SS5.Dte_Implantation > max_di.val)
```

Hope something of this will help you somehow. Good luck in refactoring =)